# Joining two different tables containing csv and display them on a webpage

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join, csv

I have been stuck with a problem and I am newbie in mysql and php, Here is the code first , so that I can explain in detail:

```
$metros = array(1,263);
foreach($metros as $metro_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT cuisine_id, cuisine_name_en FROM poi_restaurant_cuisines";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $cuisine_id = array();
    $cusine_name = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $cuisine_id[] = $row['cuisine_id'];
        $cuisine_name[] = $row['cuisine_name_en'];
    }

    foreach ($cuisine_id as $cuisine) {
        $sql = "
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM poi AS p 
                LEFT JOIN poi_restaurant AS pr USING (poi_id)
            WHERE p.poi_address_prefecture_id = '$metro_id' 
                AND pr.poi_restaurant_cuisine_id_array 
                AND  find_in_set('$cuisine', poi_restaurant_cuisine_id_array) 
                AND p.poi_status = 1";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $count_cuisine = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $count_cuisine[$metro_id][$cuisine] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
        }

        echo "<table border = 1 cellpadding= 5 cellspacing= 5 width= 100>";
        echo "<tr><th>CuisineID</th><th>Count</th></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $cuisine;
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $count_cuisine[$metro_id][$cuisine];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

The `poi_restaurant_cuisine_id_array` contains csv values. I am able to produce the count and the cuisine ID on the web page. I want to replace the cuisine ID with the name of the cuisine. I am not very good at sql or either PHP as I am a beginner. I hope I am being clear enough. Any help is highly appreciated ...Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100">';
echo "<tr><th>Cuisine</th><th>Count</th></tr>";

$metros = array(1,263);
foreach($metros as $metro_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT cuisine_id, cuisine_name_en FROM poi_restaurant_cuisines";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $cuisines = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $cuisines[] = array(
            'id'    => $row['cuisine_id'],
            'name'  => $row['cuisine_name_en'],
        );
    }

    foreach ($cuisines as $cuisine) {
        $sql = "
            SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM poi AS p 
                LEFT JOIN poi_restaurant AS pr USING (poi_id)
            WHERE p.poi_address_prefecture_id = '$metro_id' 
                AND pr.poi_restaurant_cuisine_id_array 
                AND  find_in_set('{$cuisine['id']}', poi_restaurant_cuisine_id_array) 
                AND p.poi_status = 1";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $count_cuisine = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $count_cuisine[$metro_id][$cuisine['id']] = $row['COUNT(*)'];
        }

        echo "<tr>
            <td>{$cuisine['name']}</td>
            <td>{$count_cuisine[$metro_id][$cuisine['id']]}</td>";
        </tr>";
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @shadyx Thanks so much for the answers and it worked. Sorry to bother you with an another question, as I am using the echo statements for the table inside the loop, the column names are being repeated on the page. Is there a way to avoid that. The problem is that if I use them outside the loop I wouldn't be getting the values right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cuisine_id is a unique identifier, then just use it as the array index....

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $cuisines[$row['cuisine_id']] = $row['cuisine_name_en'];
}
....
foreach ($cuisines as $cuisine_id=>$cuisine_name_en) {
```

However storing multiple values in a single column is a *very* bad idea.

Generating and running queries in a loop is another *very* bad idea.

It is possible to reduce this to a single query, declared and invloked outside the inner loop but because your data is not mormalized, this is rather complex.

Comment: Thanks so much. I do accept that storing multiple values in a single column is not good but the situation is that a restaurant can serve multiple cuisines. So we have to store all the cuisines related to that particular restaurant. But really appreciate for the time you have taken to answer the question.

Comment: That scenario does not prevent you using a normalized database.